# Is there an easier way to solve the linearization of this composite function?

Tags: calculus

Given $f(x)=x^4-4x^2-6x+4$ and $g(x) = 4x^3+3x^2-10x+2$

a. Approximate the change in $f(g(x))$ as x changes from 1 to 1.02.

b. Approximate $f(g(1.02))$

Is there an easier way to solve this problem without having to find what $f(g(x))$ is, finding the derivative of it, and also plugging in 1 and 1.02? Thanks.

Edit: answers are: a. $-0.32$ and b. $6.68$

Comment: It's not an approximation if you do that. Read the section in your Calculus book on how to approximate with differentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have to find $f(g(x))$ explicitly.

We can use chain rule to get the derivative:

$$\frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))= f'(g(x))g'(x)$$

$$f(g(x)) =f(g(1)) + \frac{d}{dx}f(g(x))|_{x=1 }(x-1)$$

Comment: [*Chen Lu*](https://youtu.be/9UWVTzhzmlE). `:)`

Answer (score 0):

To approximate the change in a function, use differentials. For example, suppose $f(x)=x^2$ and we want to know what $f(1.01)$ is. We can easily square this to get $1.0201$ which is exact but can we approximate it?

To approximate we take the derivative to get $\frac{df}{dx}=2x$ which we rewrite as $df=2xdx$.

Now we get that $f(1.01)\approx f(1)+ df=f(1) + 2(1)(.01)= 1+.02=1.02$ where $x=1$ and $dx=.01$.

You should be able to perform the same logic with $x=1$ and $dx=.02$.